# Parameter d in AttrTween is coming as undefined in angular d3js?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

The chart is rendering fine, but in the animation part it is giving error.
Here's the code.

```
chartGroup.select('.arc')
          .transition().duration(3000)
          .attrTween('d',function(d:DefaultArcObject){
               console.log(d);
               const iterpolate=d3.interpolate(0,d.endAngle);
               return (t)=>{
                  d.endAngle=interpolate(t);
                  return arc(d);
               }
          }
```

The error is given below

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endAngle')

The d parameter is coming as *undefined*.

**Versions**

- angular CLI: 9.1.2
- Node: 12.20.1
- d3: 7.3.0
- @types/d3: 7.1.0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
chartGroup.select('.arc')
      .transition().duration(3000)
      .attrTween('d',function(d:DefaultArcObject){
           console.log(d);
           const iterpolate=d3.interpolate(0,d.endAngle);
           return (t)=>{
              if(d?.endAngl) {
                 d.endAngle=interpolate(t);
              }
              return arc(d);
           }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a function without binding the js context, correct code is :

```
chartGroup.select('.arc')
          .transition().duration(3000)
          .attrTween('d',(d:DefaultArcObject) => {
               console.log(d);
               const iterpolate=d3.interpolate(0,d.endAngle);
               return (t)=>{
                  d.endAngle=interpolate(t);
                  return arc(d);
               }
          }
```

you can also add .bind(this) after your function.
You should google javascript arrow function / binding / or this if you want to deepen your knowledge on this matter.

Hope this helped